# Apollo useQuery or client.query React failing to log values

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

i am trying to loop over an array of objects from a graphql repsonse using useQuery hook.

```
 const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_FOLDERS);
```

if i console log data then i get this

[image]

but if i was to console log data.Folders[0].id i get TypeError: data is undefined i have tried creating a object with array of same values manually and i can console it fine and also if i change from using useQuery to `client.query({query: GET_FOLDERS})` with apolloBoost then it also works fine i just thought someone could point me in the right direction unless its essential i need to display all my code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `useQuery` returns result asynchronously means that the data won't be available in the initial render and hence when you try and access a particular nested property it throws you an errors

The solution is to rely on the loading state here and only access the property once its actually ready

Ex

```
const Comp = () = {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_FOLDERS);
    if(loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    console.log(data.Folders[0].id )
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a mill i knew it would be obvious wasted hours thinking i was doing something wrong in acccessing the array in object with basic JS would you have any advice on whether you are better to use client.query over useQuery in your opinion.

Comment: If you use a functional component, useQuery is a good option.

Comment: thanks for your help just in learning stage so dont alway spot the obvious things